# Android 6.0 Preview 3 device (with target sdk 23) , System.loadLibrary is fail

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, loadlibrary, target-sdk

(1) Build State
 * Target SDK : 23

(1-1) Build State - ADD
 * eclipse - indigo
 * ndk - android-ndk-r7c

(2) Device State
 * device OS : Android 6.0 preview 3 OS , Android 6.0
 * device name : Nexus 9

(3) code

case 1
    System.loadLibrary("game");

case 2
    System.load(“/lib/libc2scommon.so");

(4) Error Msg

case 1

```
09-30 19:06:56.091: D/AndroidRuntime(3512): Shutting down VM
09-30 19:06:56.091: E/AndroidRuntime(3512): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-30 19:06:56.091: E/AndroidRuntime(3512): Process: <MY_APP_ID>, PID: 3512
09-30 19:06:56.091: E/AndroidRuntime(3512): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: /data/app/<MY_APP_ID>-1/lib/arm/libgame.so: has text relocations
09-30 19:06:56.091: E/AndroidRuntime(3512):     at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:332)
09-30 19:06:56.091: E/AndroidRuntime(3512):     at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1069)
```

case 2

```
09-30 18:43:42.390: E/AndroidRuntime(3082): Process: <MY_APP_ID> , PID: 3082
09-30 18:43:42.390: E/AndroidRuntime(3082): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: /data/app/<MY_APP_ID>-2/lib/arm/libgame.so: has text relocations
09-30 18:43:42.390: E/AndroidRuntime(3082):     at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:332)
09-30 18:43:42.390: E/AndroidRuntime(3082):     at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1069)
```

What is Problem?
Target SDK 22 is not problem.
help plz.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/intl/ko/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-runtime

Comment: If your app uses the v7 appcompat library or the v7 recyclerview library, you must update your app to use to the latest versions of these libraries. -> **is fail**

Comment: Todo - eclipse update , ndk update

Comment: solution - **ndk update** (r10e) , **-fPIC** option add

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're targetting SDK 23 or higher shared libraries that have text relocations are now rejected. This is documented here:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-runtime

You'll have to fix them, which means you need to have access to the native code and NDK prepared. Easiest workaround is to add -fpic or -fPIC to your LOCAL_CFLAGS in your Android.mk file, and then rebuild the libraries.

Comment: Maybe you have to rebuild some dependancies of your .so library as well.